# Pygame issuse on mac os x 10.7.3

Tags: python, macos, image, pygame

So, I am starting with python in a mac Lion, and I am trying to make my first program with an image:
here is the code of the program

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

FPS = 30
fpsClock = pygame.time.Clock()

DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 300), 0, 32)
pygame.display.set_caption('Animation');

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
catImg = pygame.image.load("cat.png")
catx = 10
caty = 10
direction = 'right'

while True:
    DISPLAYSURF.fill(WHITE)

    if direction == 'right':
        catx += 5
        if catx == 280:
            direction = 'down'
    elif direction == 'down':
        caty += 5
        if caty == 220:
            direction = 'left'
    elif direction == 'left':
        catx -= 5
        if catx == 10:
            direction = 'up'
    elif direction == 'up':
        caty -= 5
        if caty == 10:
            direction = 'right'

    DISPLAYSURF.blit(catImg, (catx, caty))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    pygame.display.update()
    fpsClock.tick(FPS)
```

When the program runs, there is a mistake:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "catanimation.py", line 13, in <module>
    catImg = pygame.image.load("cat.png")
pygame.error: File is not a Windows BMP file
```

What could be the cause of this problem

INFO: Instead of an image I used a surface and It worked good. I suspect the problem might be related to my pygame installation but I'm not sure

Comment: Pretty sure Lion is osx 10.7.  The error message claims that the file is not in valid Windows-style BMP format.  That's what you should check.  How did you generate the image?

Comment: I just downloaded it from the internet http://inventwithpython.com/cat.png

Comment: Maybe you should keep the file extension as "png" and read it as a png, instead of reading it as a bmp.  Treating a png as a bmp will not work.

Comment: In the first place it was like that and I tried to read it like that but It didn't work, so I changed the name on my machine but I also didn't work

Comment: The first way is the correct way, and you should post your error message of that.  Right now, you're asking us why the Russian-reading machine can't read your English book after you changed the cover to Russian.

Answer (score 3):

Your code actually worked "out of the box" for me on Python 2.6 (Mac OS X 10.6).

If you're using the Python version supplied with your OS (Apple 2.7) make sure you're using this package: [Pygame for Apple supplied Python - Mac OS X 10.7](http://www.pygame.org/ftp/pygame-1.9.2pre-py2.7-macosx10.7.mpkg.zip) .

Comment: I'll test it out and will let you know