# pygame error on Mac OSX 10.7.4

Tags: python, osx-lion, pygame

```
**pygame.image.load("ball.PNG") error: File is not a Windows BMP file**
```

I am getting the above error every time i try to load any image other than `.BMP`. I searched the internet for a solution and nothing has worked.
The `SDL_image` library is where it should be but python seems to be ignoring it!!

```
pygame.image.get_extended() // returns 0
```

I am running `python-2.7.3`...and `pygame-1.9.2pre-py2.7-macosx10.7`

If anyone can point me in the right direction it would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Duplicate question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10069394/pygame-issuse-on-mac-os-x-10-7-3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it to work! If you install Pygame for Python 2.7, for OS X 10.3 instead of the newer version that apple has supplied which was:
python-2.7.3...and pygame-1.9.2pre-py2.7-macosx10.7...everything works perfect!

install the Pygame for Python 2.7 for OS X 10.3:
http://pygame.org/ftp/pygame-1.9.1release-python.org-32bit-py2.7-macosx10.3.dmg

Comment: Hey, I accidentally clicked the down arrow (don't know how) but this totally fixed it for me. I meant to up-vote it. It says I can't change my vote until the answer is edited, so feel free to edit it and I'll come back and change my vote. :P

Comment: Hey, no problem! I am glad it was of benefit to someone, I remember that error that error drove me mad!